# NPM lockfiles do not handle transitive dependencies correctly

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, node-modules, package.json

On my current project we have dependencies listed with the exact version *(e. g. `babel-core: '6.5.2'`)* in our `package.json` file.

But after the recent project build *(which includes running `npm install` on the build machine)* some node modules were updated and our artifact got broken.

The research has shown that although we have the exact versions mentioned in `package.json` file, the required module might have dependency on itself through its dependency, and both of them are using the caret dependencies. In our case it appeared to be

- `babel-core: '6.5.2'` depending on
- `babel-register: '^6.16.0'` depending on
- `babel-core: '^6.9.0'` resolved as `babel-core: '6.26.0'` (because of the [caret range rules](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004))

And the specified `babel-core` version breaks our builds.

We've tried creating `package-lock.json` files in order to prevent these transitive dependencies to be resolved the way they *were* resolved.

But, as [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks) on `package-lock` files states:

> Whenever you run npm install, npm generates or updates your package lock

And thus, all the packages depending on `babel-core` with caret version are resolved with incorrect version of a module.

After taking a closer look at `package-lock.json` file, I don't see it's worth changing it because of

1. the snowball effect - changing one dependency requires to change all the others, depending on it *(and this is recursive process)*
2. the need of verifying both the existence of the version you're about to change to **and** its hash *(for the `integrity` field)*

The question is: how do I install the exact versions of all the modules, mentioned in my `package.json` file, preventing NPM to resolve it again with a different version?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`npm shrinkwrap`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap), it is used for transitive lock.

Comment: I am having the same issue. shrinkwrap is good when you have everything working. But when you have an issue you are "freezing" the problem.